# Technician.Dispatch.exe requires elevated permissions to run

Tags: c#

I have an application called Technician.Dispatch.exe and any time I try to run the application it requires elevated permissions to run. Here are the relevant project files.

**Technician.Dispatch.csproj**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{D1B2C77B-4547-44E6-A453-9F1266E63AFF}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>Technician.Dispatch</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Technician.Dispatch</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <NoWin32Manifest>true</NoWin32Manifest>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

**Program.cs**

```
using System;

namespace Technician.Dispatch
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs**

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Technician.Dispatch")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("Technician.Dispatch")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2016")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]

// Setting ComVisible to false makes the types in this assembly not visible 
// to COM components.  If you need to access a type in this assembly from 
// COM, set the ComVisible attribute to true on that type.
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]

// The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
[assembly: Guid("d1b2c77b-4547-44e6-a453-9f1266e63aff")]

// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Removing the following code from the `.csproj` fixes the issue.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <NoWin32Manifest>true</NoWin32Manifest>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Why does removing that code resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you chose to "Create application without a manifest" in your [project properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247046.aspx):

The default option "Embed manifest with default settings":

> Supports the typical manner in which Visual Studio operates on Windows Vista, which is to embed security information in the application's executable file, specifying that **requestedExecutionLevel** be **AsInvoker**. This is the default option.

(emphasis theirs)

To extract the reason why:

Embedding the manifest containing the security information *"Run this application with the privileges of the invoker"* spares you from having to explicitly grant execution privileges to acquire the needed security information.

Comment: I'm not accepting this answer because my question is *_why_* removing the code works. If I were to name this project `Technician.Send` instead it would have no trouble running without elevated permissions. What significance is the name of the project/namespace

Comment: The name has nothing to do with this - the quoted part of your .csproj exactly controls the described project setting.

Comment: So explain why the same csproj settings for a project named `Technician.Send` doesn't have this problem. It has no manifest and doesn't require elevated permissions

Comment: In your question you state removing the PropertyGroup solved the issue you experienced - you should explain why renaming your project has anything to do with this now.

Comment: Because that was my specific question which I am seeking an answer for.

Comment: The project name has nothing to do with this. Period.

Comment: I took a video of me doing the experiment, which you can watch here: https://youtu.be/zx-JhzbxjYo but I encourage you to try the experiment for yourself.